# How to avoid noise,after applying the effects of bitmap using the color lut?

Tags: android, image, filter, bitmap, lookup-tables

Hi i am applying the effect on bitmap images using the 4x4 color lut.Effects are applied but some noise(shades in the image) in the effected images.
How to avoid this noise and image quality also missing?

i am using below code to apply the filter effects.

```
final static int X_DEPTH = 16;
final static int Y_DEPTH = 16; //One little square has 16x16 pixels in it 
final static int ROW_DEPTH = 4;
final static int COLUMN_DEPTH = 4; // the image consists of 4x4 little    squares
final static int COLOR_DISTORTION = 16; // 256*256*256 => 256 no distortion,    64*64*64 => 256 dividied by 4 = 64, 16x16x16 => 256 dividied by 16 = 16


private Bitmap applyLutToBitmap(Bitmap src, Bitmap lutBitmap) {

int lutWidth = lutBitmap.getWidth();
int lutColors[] = new int[lutWidth * lutBitmap.getHeight()];
lutBitmap.getPixels(lutColors, 0, lutWidth, 0, 0, lutWidth,   lutBitmap.getHeight());

int mWidth = src.getWidth();
int mHeight = src.getHeight();
int[] pix = new int[mWidth * mHeight];
src.getPixels(pix, 0, mWidth, 0, 0, mWidth, mHeight);

int R, G, B;
for (int y = 0; y < mHeight; y++)
    for (int x = 0; x < mWidth; x++) {
        int index = y * mWidth + x;
        int r = ((pix[index] >> 16) & 0xff) / COLOR_DISTORTION;
        int g = ((pix[index] >> 8) & 0xff) / COLOR_DISTORTION;
        int b = (pix[index] & 0xff) / COLOR_DISTORTION;

        int lutIndex = getLutIndex(lutWidth, r, g, b);

        R = ((lutColors[lutIndex] >> 16) & 0xff);
        G = ((lutColors[lutIndex] >> 8) & 0xff);
        B = ((lutColors[lutIndex]) & 0xff);
        pix[index] = 0xff000000 | (R << 16) | (G << 8) | B;
    }
Bitmap filteredBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(mWidth, mHeight, src.getConfig());
filteredBitmap.setPixels(pix, 0, mWidth, 0, 0, mWidth, mHeight);
return filteredBitmap;
}

//the magic happens here
private int getLutIndex(int lutWidth, int redDepth, int greenDepth, int    blueDepth) {
int lutX = (greenDepth % ROW_DEPTH) * X_DEPTH + blueDepth;
int lutY = (greenDepth / COLUMN_DEPTH) * Y_DEPTH + redDepth;
return lutY * lutWidth + lutX;
}
```

below link is my lut ,original image and filter effected image https://i.stack.imgur.com/R1jLc.jpg

please see the effected image some noise are coming in the effected image and quality of the image also missing.How to apply filter effects with out noise and without missing the image quality using the 4x4 lut?